# Android Volley String Request response string

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I want to check the string which is been responded from the server php file that it is empty or not
currently i am using this code:-

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String res) {
    if(res != ""){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

But the problem is that it always run the code whether the string responded is empty or not.
like it shows the toast message when the responded string is empty and also shows it when it is not empty. its pretty annoying please help.

Comment: Try trimming the line and then check. Check for newline character at the end of line. And use equals method as Egor suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You should never compare strings in Java using `==` or `!=`, instead use the equals() method:

```
if (!"".equals(res))
```